# User Training Materials

Tags: documentation

Does anybody know of any good publicly-available Wordpress training materials (videos, manuals, etc.) that could be used to give content editors a basic overview of Wordpress. We have a a handful of blogs on a Wordpress server and I'd really like to be able to automate training some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interconnect/Spectacula folks manage free [WordPress User Guide](http://spectacu.la/wordpress-30-user-guide/) for training users.

Answer (score 2):

[lynda](http://lynda.com) has a great series