# WordPress training materials

Tags: documentation, references

Are there any good publicly-available WordPress training materials (videos, manuals, etc.) that could be used to give content editors a basic overview of WordPress?

We have a handful of blogs on a WordPress server and I'd really like to be able to automate training some more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User Training Materials](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/user-training-materials)

Answer (score 2):

[VTC](http://www.vtc.com/products/WordPress-Blogging-Tutorials.htm) and [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/home/ViewCourses.aspx?lpk0=841) have very good training videos on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this site](http://www.blogbriefing.com) particularly useful in terms of WordPress video tutorials and training.

<sup>I am not affiliated with the above site in any way, just pointing out a resource that I found useful.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[Learning WordPress](http://learning.wordpress.com/) and [WordPress.tv](http://wordpress.tv/) are both great resources!

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) is really the first and best place to start for WordPress questions and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I teach a WordPress Training Course and offer a [free training manual](http://www.marketersmojo.com/report/WordPressWebsiteHowTo.pdf) you might find helpful.

I think the manual will help you get a good overall understanding of how WordPress works and the main sections you can use to update your existing sites. Hope it helps!